# Build RPM to deploy

Tags: deployment, rpm, fabric, best-fit

I would like to know what is the best method to deploy applications like Django, Flask etc.. is by building RPM files or by using a tool like [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/en/latest/) which more or less does the same thing.. I'm trying to figure out the best approach to handle deployment and automation.

Comment: Question is very broad and open to opinion. Generally speaking it's never a bad idea to package software for its target platform. That way you can leverage the native installer.

Answer (score 0):

After considering the requirements I believe in my situation fabric will work best for basic deployments to multiple servers. While rpms can do similar things every time there is a change in source a new RPM must be created which for my environment will not work since the source code changes frequently. Any input from anyone is welcome. But I feel at least for me this will work best in the current situation.